# In javascript the timestamp of the same time is different

Tags: javascript

```
console.log(+new Date("2017-6-18"), +new Date("2017-06-18"));
//1497715200000 1497744000000

console.log(new Date("2017-6-18"), new Date("2017-06-18"));
//Sun Jun 18 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (中国标准时间) Sun Jun 18 2017 08:00:00 GMT+0800 (中国标准时间)
```

The time "2017-6-18" and "2017-06-18" is same, but the  timestamp of them is different

Comment: The behaviour of `new Date("2017-06-18")` is guaranteed by the JavaScript specification. `new Date("2017-6-18")` doesn’t follow the spec format and browsers can do anything with it (including interpreting it in a different timezone); don’t use it.

Comment: Chrome treats those formats differently - firefox doesn't - so, as Ryan pointed out, use date formats that are in the spec, don't rely on how a browser may handle any "non-standard" format

Comment: Thank you！It  just like “Follow the rules and make fewer mistakes”